# Не удаляются сессии в django

Tags: python, django

Время хранения сессии 6 секунд, указал в методе set_expiry(), но после обновления страницы через 6 секунд сессия не удаляется.

views.py:

```
def add_racion(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddRacionForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        meal = form.cleaned_data['meal']
        request.session['meal'] = str(meal)
        food = form.cleaned_data['food']
        request.session['food'] = str(food)
        gramm = form.cleaned_data['gramm']
        request.session['gramm'] = str(gramm)
        request.session.set_expiry(6)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = AddRacionForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request,'bjuk/add_racion.html', context)
else:
    form = AddRacionForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'bjuk/add_racion.html', context)
```

Comment: Вы хотите полностью удалить сессию?

Comment: Да, нужно чтобы удаляло полностью.